# Autostart deluge daemon 1.3.10 on boot on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, init.d

I have already been through different tutorials on how to set raspberry pi into a torrent box, but I think most of the how-to tutorials are out-dated.

I have also check my version of deluge daemon using his command:

```
deluge -v
```

And it returns this:

```
deluged: 1.3.10
libtorrent: 0.16.18.0
```

I have followed the How-To Geek tutorial so far.

Link: http://www.howtogeek.com/142044/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-an-always-on-bittorrent-box/

After I stared to get errors I have fully uninstalled and deleted all the files of deluge.

The tutorial suggests this command:

```
sudo wget -O /etc/default/deluge-daemon http://cdn5.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/gg/up/sshot5151a8c86fb85.txt
```

But there is no such file as /etc/default/deluge-daemon, instead there is a deluged named file (maybe short for deluge-daemon in new version)

Basically what the command does is that it copies the content of the file http://cdn5.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/gg/up/sshot5151a8c86fb85.txt to the file located at /etc/default/deluge-daemon.

As I can't find deluged-daemon, I chose to do this with /etc/default/deluged

The original content of /etc/default/deluged:

```
# Defaults for deluged initscript
# sourced by /etc/init.d/deluged

# change to 1 to enable daemon
ENABLE_DELUGED=0
```

Content provided on the file http://cdn5.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/gg/up/sshot5151a8c86fb85.txt:

```
# Configuration for /etc/init.d/deluge-daemon

# The init.d script will only run if this variable non-empty.
DELUGED_USER="pi"             # !!!CHANGE THIS!!!!

# Should we run at startup?
RUN_AT_STARTUP="YES"
```

But both files looks different and the deluge daemon doesn't load up on startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue using this guide: http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/Service/systemd.

1. Follow instructions from this guide (you may skip deluge-web instructions).
2. Note that `deluge` user was created with `--home /var/lib/deluge`.
3. Update `auth` (setup an account) and `core.conf` (set `allow_remote` flag) files in home dir of `deluge` user (as opposed to home dir of `pi` user that is usually mentioned in other tutorials).
4. Reboot